# Scrollable table with sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want sortable table with scrolling with header fixed. I want these feature with jQuery or normal Javascript.

I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). This is an elegant jquery plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an advanced one take a look at

[Flexigrid for jQuery](http://www.flexigrid.info/)

> Lightweight but rich data grid with
>   resizable columns and a scrolling data
>   to match the headers, plus an ability
>   to connect to an xml based data source
>   using Ajax to load the content.